# BundleTransformer: Bootstrap SASS

Tags: c#, sass, bootstrap-4, bundletransformer

I am using the excellent [BundleTransformer](https://github.com/Taritsyn/BundleTransformer) Nuget package to dynamically compile SCSS using the ASP.NET bundling and minification pipeline.  I am attempting to bring in the [bootstrap.sass](https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap.sass/) package into the mix, and keep receiving the error below.  My setup is pretty simple at this point, and the scss file compiles just fine with the `node-sass` tool, and if I remove the `@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.scss"` line, the SCSS compiles perfectly with BundleTransformer.  Has anyone run into this issue and possibly have a solution?  This is .NET Framework 4.7.2.
Thank you!

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
        var nullBuilder = new NullBuilder();
        var styleTransformer = new StyleTransformer();
        var scriptTransformer = new ScriptTransformer();
        var nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();

        var defaultScssBundle = new CustomStyleBundle("~/bundles/styles/default");
        defaultScssBundle.Include(
            "~/Content/Default.scss"
        );
        defaultScssBundle.Builder = nullBuilder;
        defaultScssBundle.Transforms.Add(styleTransformer);
        defaultScssBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
        defaultScssBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
        bundles.Add(defaultScssBundle);
```

**Default.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";

/* common styles */
.green {
    color: green;
}

.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Error**

```
During translation of SCSS code, readed from the file '/TestProject/Content/bootstrap/_alert.scss', to CSS code syntax error has occurred.
See more details:

Error: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding-y".
       on line 7:12 of Content/bootstrap/_alert.scss
>>   padding: $alert-padding-y $alert-padding-x;
  -----------^

Error code: 1
Description: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding-y".
File: /TestProject/Content/bootstrap/_alert.scss
Line number: 7
Column number: 12
Source fragment:

Line 6:   position: relative;
Line 7:   padding: $alert-padding-y $alert-padding-x;
-------------------^
Line 8:   margin-bottom: $alert-margin-bottom;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I found the problem.  After looking at the [sample in the Github Repo](https://github.com/Taritsyn/BundleTransformer/blob/master/samples/BundleTransformer.Sample.AspNet45.Mvc4/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs), I pulled the following lines out of `BundleConfig.cs` and all is working now.

```
defaultScssBundle.Builder = nullBuilder;
defaultScssBundle.Transforms.Add(styleTransformer);
defaultScssBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
```